# NativeScript HTTP Request Promise + WebApi Error

Tags: c#, nativescript

Using NativeScript, I am getting an error calling my C# WebApi if I do so in the "then" callback function of another HTTP request:

```
request({
    url: 'API_ONE_URL',
    method: 'GET'
}).then((response: HttpResponse) => {
    request({
        url: 'API_TWO_URL',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((response: HttpResponse) => {
        // Do something
    }, (e) => {
    });
}, (e) => {
});
```

The error I get is "Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated." It does not matter what sort of API I call. I created the following API to test an "empty" controller:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class EX_TestController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Success = true });
        }
    }
}
```

"API_ONE_URL" works fine. If I call "API_TWO_URL" outside of the request callback function , it works fine. But if I call "API_TWO" inside of the callback for "API_ONE", I get that error.

I am stumped, any insight would be awesome!

Comment: Sounds to me that is from your API itself and nothing seems specific to {N} here.

Comment: May be did you try calling third party stubs, for instance https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/